# Windows 8 app refuses to connect to Azure service with a proxy running

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, proxy, windows-8

I've got an app in the Windows 8 store that uses a WCF service hosted on Azure. When I use my proxy program, [UltraSurf](http://ultrasurf.us/), the app fails to connect to the service with this error:

> The content type text/html of the response message does not match the
>   content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a
>   custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is
>   implemented properly. The first 472 bytes of the response were:
>   '
>
> The requested URL could not be retrieved
>
> '.

The URL mentioned in the quote is the default 'can't find the page Url' that UltraSurf produces and so the error message is probably of no use. The question is, why/how does Ultrasurf block/get in the way of my connection?

Can anybody shed some light on what's going on and why it fails connect please?

Thanks!

Comment: No - at least not intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

Working without much information here, but I'd suspect that the problem is that the proxy is just being a little picky.

I believe that your error message basically says, "I'm expecting to get back 'text/xml' data, but what I see is 'text/html' data".  That's probably not because it can actually see 'text/html' data coming back, but rather, because it's not seeing the content type header from the response telling it that it *is* xml data.

I don't know exactly how you implemented your WCF service, or what type of data it's set up to return, but you might want to ensure that you explicitly set the content type somewhere in your code before the return and see what happens.  Something like:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
```

The only other thing that springs to mind is that your application might be picky about the content type for XML in general.  There's a bit of, um... [subtle difference](http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/489)... around whether the appropriate content type for XML is 'application/xml' or 'text/xml'.  It's possible that your service is presenting the one that your proxy doesn't like?

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't provide any more detail. My WP7 app, which uses the same service runs fine in the WP7 emulator. Where would I set Response.ContentType?